# Is it possible to have group properties such as material properties in Three JS?

Tags: three.js

ThreeJS supports object groups but each object has its own material and properties.

Is there a way to have shared properties such as alpha values?

In PixiJS for example, a parent container can have an alpha value that gets applied to all the children. Same with masks. ThreeJS groups don't have material properties.

What is the best way to animate an alpha fade on a group of objects in ThreeJS? I can animate a single value and iterate over all the children changing their material properties to match but this would complicate changing both the child object properties and the parent.

I would need to store my own properties per object like alpha and then set the resulting alpha on the material to the product of the alpha values up the hierarchy e.g

```
Three.Group - alpha = 0.5
|
Three.Group - alpha = 0.5
|
Three.Sprite_1 - alpha = 0.5 set material alpha to 0.5 x 0.5 x 0.5 = 0.125
Three.Sprite_2 - alpha = 1 set material alpha to 1 x 0.5 x 0.5 = 0.25
```

I could animate the top group's custom alpha property and all Sprites in the group would fade. Is this the recommended way to do it or is there a better way to do group properties?

The main properties I'm interested in sharing between objects with different materials are masks (alpha masks and clipping planes) and alpha values.

Comment: Objects can only share materials. But different materials can't share object properties like `opacity`. It might be possible in the future with the experimental `NodeMaterial` (https://threejs.org/examples/?q=nodes).